Issue with smac planner going crazy at goal reaching
I'm getting an issue with SmacPlannerLattice, almost everytime I give the planner a destination. It calculates a well feasible path but when my robot is reaching the goal the planner goes crazy and creates loop around destination and the robot just do it and it can happen many times in a row. I recorded the rviz view of my simulation:

I'm using ros humble. I think it's an issue with my smac planner configuration. I tried to debug using gdb, I didn't get any informations only of new threads beginning.
Here are my plugins parameters:
coverage_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    default_headland_width: 0.25
    robot_width: 0.925
    operation_width: 0.925
    min_turning_radius: 0.5
    linear_curv_change: 2.0
    coordinates_in_cartesian_frame: true
    default_allow_overlap: true
    default_turn_point_distance: 0.3 # distance between points
    default_swath_angle_type: "SET_ANGLE"
    default_swath_angle: 0.0 # We know its aligned for the demo

row_coverage_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    robot_width: 0.925
    operation_width: 0.925
    min_turning_radius: 0.5
    linear_curv_change: 2.0
    coordinates_in_cartesian_frame: true
    default_swath_type: "CENTER"
    default_offset: 0.0


bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    navigators: ["navigate_to_pose", "navigate_through_poses"]
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"

    # default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: "/home/edmlt/TEAMGREEN/tgbot_sdk_ros2/src/ros2/tg_bot_ros2/config/behavior_trees/custom_coverage_bt.xml"
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node
      - opennav_compute_complete_coverage_action_bt_node
    error_code_names:
      - compute_path_error_code
      - follow_path_error_code


controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"]
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController"
      desired_linear_vel: 0.5
      max_linear_accel: 2.0
      max_linear_decel: 2.5
      lookahead_dist: 0.6
      min_lookahead_dist: 0.3
      max_lookahead_dist: 0.9
      lookahead_time: 1.5
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 1.8
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      use_velocity_scaled_lookahead_dist: false
      min_approach_linear_velocity: 0.05
      use_approach_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      max_allowed_time_to_collision: 1.0
      use_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      use_cost_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: false
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_radius: 0.9
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_speed: 0.25
      use_rotate_to_heading: true
      rotate_to_heading_min_angle: 0.785
      max_angular_accel: 3.2
      cost_scaling_dist: 0.3
      cost_scaling_gain: 1.0
      inflation_cost_scaling_factor: 3.0

# GPS WPF CHANGE: Remove static layer
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.22
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      always_send_full_costmap: True

# GPS WPF CHANGE: Remove static layer
# GPS WPF CHANGE: Set rolling global costmap with 50x50 size. See note below
global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      robot_radius: 0.22
      resolution: 0.1
      # When using GPS navigation you will potentially traverse huge environments which are not practical to
      # fit on a big static costmap. Thus it is recommended to use a rolling global costmap large enough to 
      # contain each pair of successive waypoints. See: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2174
      rolling_window: True
      width: 50
      height: 50
      track_unknown_space: true
      # no static map
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          # outdoors there will probably be more inf points
          inf_is_valid: true
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True

# The yaml_filename does not need to be specified since it going to be set by defaults in launch.
# If you'd rather set it in the yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py
# file & provide full path to map below. If CLI map configuration or launch default is provided, that will be used.
# map_server:
#   ros__parameters:
#     yaml_filename: ""

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    use_sim_time: True

    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerLattice" # In Iron and older versions, "/" was used instead of "::"
      allow_unknown: true                 # Allow traveling in unknown space
      tolerance: 1.0                     # dist-to-goal heuristic cost (distance) for valid tolerance endpoints if exact goal cannot be found.
      max_iterations: 1000000             # Maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000    # Maximum number of iterations after within tolerances to continue to try to find exact solution
      max_planning_time: 5.0              # Max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5       # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0  # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
      analytic_expansion_max_cost: 200.0  # The maximum single cost for any part of an analytic expansion to contain and be valid, except when necessary on approach to goal
      analytic_expansion_max_cost_override: false  #  Whether or not to override the maximum cost setting if within critical distance to goal (ie probably required)
      reverse_penalty: 2.0                # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 1.0               # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.5          # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                   # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      rotation_penalty: 5.0               # Penalty to apply to in-place rotations, if minimum control set contains them
      retrospective_penalty: 0.015
      lattice_filepath: "/home/edmlt/TEAMGREEN/tgbot_sdk_ros2/src/ros2/nav2_smac_planner/lattice_primitives/sample_primitives/5cm_resolution/1m_turning_radius/diff/output.json"                # The filepath to the state lattice graph
      lookup_table_size: 20.0             # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: false     # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
      allow_reverse_expansion: false      # If true, allows the robot to use the primitives to expand in the mirrored opposite direction of the current robot's orientation (to reverse).
      smooth_path: True                   # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path
      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true
        refinement_num: 2

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True
      w_smooth: 0.4

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    local_costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    global_costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    local_footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    local_frame: odom
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2


velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0
    

Any help or advises would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Unfortunately, that gif is so small, I can't really see what's happening.

I tried to take more videos. For setup reason, it's simpler for me to record with my phone:
link
link
link
I didn't precise but my robot is a 4 wheel diff drive

Is there a way to get more indormation from planner in xterm with gdb? I only get this:
[Thread 0x7fffb3c7e640 (LWP 15493) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffc8c3a640 (LWP 15506)]
[Thread 0x7fffc8c3a640 (LWP 15506) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffb3c7e640 (LWP 15518)]
[Thread 0x7fffb3c7e640 (LWP 15518) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffc8c3a640 (LWP 15524)]
[Thread 0x7fffc8c3a640 (LWP 15524) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffb3c7e640 (LWP 15528)]
